# How to do intheContextof in javascript so that scope could be changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

b/c I'm using angular js, I often have parsing headaches looking at $rootScope.something

is it possible to do a

```
 function inthecontextof(obj, func){
     func.call(obj);
 }
```

where I could just do

```
inthecontextof($rootScope, function(){
    flamingo = 5 //$rootScope.flamingo is what im refering to
    $apply()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to write it like this:

```
inthecontextof($rootScope, function(){
    this.flamingo = 5 //$rootScope.flamingo is what im refering to
    $apply()
}
```

Now I'm not sure what you expect "$apply" to do here; if it's going to implicitly reference "$rootScope" then that should be OK.